# Loading Text, Memory use exeeds Size on Disk

Tags: c#, text

I have an odd problem, I have a ConcurrentDictionary, loading a text file, and he text file is 3.4Gb on disk, but when I load the ConcurrentDictionary, the size in RAM is 14GB - What have I done wrong?

```
protected ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> BaseVocabulary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

public async Task<bool> LoadVocabularyFileAsync(string path)
{

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] Split = line.Split(' ');
                string Word = Split[0];


                int Index;

                if (!int.TryParse(Split[1], out Index))
                    throw new InvalidDataException("The data Format is invalid!");


                if (!ContainsWord(Word))
                    if (!BaseVocabulary.TryAdd(Word, Index))
                        QueueWord(Word);
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
}

public bool ContainsWord(string word)
{
    return BaseVocabulary.ContainsKey(word);
}

private void QueueWord(string word)
{
    Queue.Add(word);
}
```

How can I make this more efficient, RAM is important in my App, I need to free it up, I was hoping size on disk was RAM.

EDIT:
As requested, each line would be of structure:

```
the 2000000
```

there fore the Concurrent Dictionary would look like:

```
BaseVocabulary.Key = the;
BaseVocabulary.Value = 2000000
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The text file is probably compressed which is why the RAM is larger than file.  Additionally the dictionary create a hash table which adds to the RAM size.  You have done nothing wrong.  I would make sure you check the RAM size after the streams are closed.

Comment: Editing to remove important information is invalid, flag amongst yourselves all you want, don't remove important information pertaining to the question,

Comment: @Mike Hofer - hope it helps you! Queue is a ConcurrentBag<string>

Comment: It's a bit naive to think you could load text into a data structure with _no overhead_. Things that would take up memory on top of the file size: (1) .NET `char`s are 16 bits. Bytes are 8 bits. If your file is mostly alphanumeric, that would double the memory usage right there (3.4 -> 6.8) (2) Any data structure is going to consist of overheads in the form of references, fields, etc. `ConcurrentDictionary` includes a hash table and probably other components. Basically, if you don't want to take up 14 GB of RAM then _don't load your entire 3.4 GB file into a data structure._

Comment: @JLRishe - According to MS, a char is 1 byte (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx), please reference your source.

Comment: @RustyNail Also, what is the data type of `Queue`? I notice that you are searching the dictionary, which theoretically contains the word list, but then adding the word to a different structure. How many copies of this data do you have in memory?

Comment: @MikeHofer actually he's trying to add it to his ConcurrentDictionary. If that fails, he adds it to Queue, which he stated in an earlier comment is ConcurrentBag<string>

Rusty Nail -- can you give an example of the data/lines you're using?  Just a small one to get a taste.

Comment: @MikeHofer - Queue is a catch, only for failures. Its of type String. Last I checked there was about 10 in there, mostly empty.

Comment: @RustyNail I did a test with dummy data and got > 5% greater than my file size in memory, which is likely the extra space needed to store ints.  If i get an idea of your data structure coming in, I might have a better idea for you

Comment: @oppassum - yes, about 4.6 for me. Ints are store in the same file, so one line in the file is `the 2000000` I edited the question to explain further.

Comment: char is 2 bytes in c#. You don't need us to provide references, basic research will yield this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've researched this quite a bit, and while I can't find any exact information from Microsoft, I have found [This Website](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-memory) discussing the amount of memory used per unit.  This test was done with a dictionary instead of a concurrentdictionary.  Concurrentdictionaries likely have added overhead for thread safety.

Re-performing the test myself with ConcurrentDictionary, using 1 string character and 1 int value, I see it adding 72 bytes each time something is added.

My guess is what you're seeing is the overhead of the ConcurrentDictionary, and other than choosing another way to store your data, I'm not sure you'll have any luck making this better.

Perhaps it might be easier for your purposes to take care of the synchronization yourself.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. The built in type `sizeof(char)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sizeof) provides a useful indication, as stated in a comment above, char is 1 byte in C and sizeof returns `2` for char in C#, being Unicode, this obtains the size in bytes for an unmanaged type. Right away we are dealing with a 2x factor increase in .NET

Comment: @RustyNail While this is true, I did read some documentation saying that you can't be certain that an unmanaged type will use the same amount of memory as a managed type/in managed code.  The point being that managed could potentially use more.

Comment: I just cant believe 50% of RAM Usage is Class Overhead. See: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,3fc8b6e4e28ee36c for a small code example of a simple threadsafe collection, where is the overhead going, not doubling of information there.

Comment: Found it, there does seem to be a double copy of the list: `volatile ThreadLocalList m_headList, m_tailList;`Therefore doubling the size of the Collection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we have a more concise answer.

It appears as part of the thread safety, Concurrent collections do make two copies of the collection:
 https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,a1bdd7135f94cbdb

```
volatile ThreadLocalList m_headList, m_tailList;

ThreadLocalList currentList = m_headList;

// Acquire the lock to update the m_tailList pointer
lock (GlobalListsLock)
{
if (m_headList == null)
{
list = new ThreadLocalList(Thread.CurrentThread);
m_headList = list;
m_tailList = list;
}
else
{

list = GetUnownedList();
if (list == null)
{
list = new ThreadLocalList(Thread.CurrentThread);
m_tailList.m_nextList = list;
m_tailList = list;
}
}
m_locals.Value = list;
```

So it appears that Concurrent Collections do make two copies `m_headList` and a second copy `m_tailList`, effectively doubling the List size, which explains the approximate 4.6 times disk size used. From around 3.4 to just over 14Gb.

So, in .NET, char is 2 bytes and not 1 byte (factor 2x), and then the List is doubled in the Concurrent Dictionary again (factor 2x again), then a little overhead on the data structure which makes a lot more sense.

Using a custom Dictionary class, I got this down to 11Gb. With a bit more work, maybe more, it's also much faster to load.